# RazorGenerator precompiled views and related scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, razorgenerator, asp.net-bundling

recently while I'm using with a great satisfaction RazorGenerator for my precompiled views (internal or external library as per needs) I'm involved in 
a such of critical question about... and for library/compiled views required javascripts?

How can be accomplished that? maybe using a Bundling reading from embedded css or js or else from external library?

Any suggestion is really appreciated!
Regards

Answer (score 1):

At one of my old positions we looked into it. In our situation(which may or may not be similar to yours), we bundled the custom css and javascript and got a little bit of a performance boost, enough for management to say it was worth it. We actually used a CDN for getting the content shared (JQuery, Bootstrap, etc...). When I left I know they were discussing a hybrid, CDN bundling approach.

It will really depend on your application circumstances though, I think the performance gain they achieved was a few hundred milliseconds.